# How to create partitioned tables from templates in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to create new tables with a table template.
My template is partitioned and I would also like the newly generated tables to be partitioned as well, but, from my tests, it seems that they aren't.

Is there a way to instruct that newly generated tables from a template should also be partitioned?

Comment: How do you create new tables with a table template? Are you referring to the template table used for streaming, https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#template-tables? For partitioned tables the streaming data will automatically go to a new partition so template table is not needed.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to tables created automatically when streaming. As far as I have experimented, these cannot be partitioned, even if the template is.

Comment: The template table for streaming is a temporary workaround to create daily tables, before partitioned tables was introduced. With partitioned tables the streaming data will automatically go to new partitions, so I'm not sure why do you still want to create new tables from the template table?

Comment: The scenario is this: I have many data types I would like to store each one in a different table (around 200 in total). These datatypes all share the same structure, and I would prefer having them in separate tables rather than only one for optimisation. I could create all tables beforehand, although the automatic creation was appealing because it could save me time.
Anyway, it's perfectly feasible also to create the tables either by hand or programmatically without using the auto-creation from streaming data.
Thanks for your reply.